# Same exposure for Array typed param

Tags: java

First sorry if the title is wrong, i am new to java.

I want create method that if the input are class of an object then its yield are object, but if the input are class of Array of object, then its yield array of object.

```
public final static <T extends BaseClass> T fromJson(String json, Class<? extends BaseClass> klas) throws JsonSyntaxException {
    return (T) GSON.fromJson(json, klas);
}

public final static <T extends BaseClass> T[] fromJson(String json, Class<? extends BaseClass[]> klas) throws JsonSyntaxException {
    return (T[]) GSON.fromJson(json, klas);
}
```

so the usage is:

```
BaseClass r = fromJson("{}", BaseClass.class);
BaseClass[] r2 = fromJson("{}", BaseClass[].class);
```

but the compiler said both method have same closure, how to handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, thanks to Type Erasure, the signatures that get compiled to bytecode are as follows:

```
public final static BaseClass fromJson(String json, Class klas) throws JsonSyntaxException {
    return (BaseClass) GSON.fromJson(json, klas);
}

public final static BaseClass[] fromJson(String json, Class klas) throws JsonSyntaxException {
    return (BaseClass[]) GSON.fromJson(json, klas);
}
```

As you can see, the signatures are effectively the same.

The best you can really do is rename one or both of these methods to have different names.